# Save and Recover Layout on Daemon

Tags: emacs

I'm aware of the use of lisp funcitons window-configuration-to-register and jump-to-register, and also packages like desktop.el and winner-mode.

These can all be used to save a layout during a session and recover it sometime later.  I can get these to work nicely.

However if I'm running in daemon mode and am attached via emacsclient - if I try save a layout to a register, for example - I do not seem to be able to recover this layout in a separate emacsclient on the same daemon using any of the above methods - even though they share exactly the same windows.

Can anyone suggest a lisp function or any other methodology to allow to persisting of a client window layout after closing the original emacsclient session?

I should add I have no option but to use use emacs in console.

**Update:**

To half-answer my own question -

Saving the frame configuration to a register seems to work:

```
C-x r f – frame-configuration-to-register
C-x r j – jump-to-register
```

It's a bit shakey - when you jump back to the register you seem to have to exit the frame using 'C-x 5 0'.... after that you're still left with an underlying client frame that you can exist using 'C-x C-c' without killing the daemon.

If you try to directly exit the register stored frame using other methods it will either not work at all, or you'll kill the daemon entirely!

So it looks to me like jumping to the register seems to kinda grab ownership of the daemon process.

So follow-up questions:
1) Is there a way to make this play a bit nicer with the daemon?
2) Is there a way to automatically save your frame to a register (which will persist on the daemon) when emacs client exits or dies?

**2nd Update**

Actually having used it for a day - the above doesn't really work at all - the behaviour is random when restoring windows - sometimes it works, and it is often impossible to quit the emacsclient using any command!

I often find myself running kill on the emacsclient - which in-turn kills the daemon process as well as the client!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question and having tried many ways to achieve the above, I've only found one method that at least so far has proved stable/reliable even when using the daemon - this is to use the workgroups2 pacakge that is available on Melpa.

I also noted that the original workgroups package (of which workgroups2 is a more recent fork) also works, but has more limited funcitonality.  This is also available from Melpa.

The key default commands on workgroups2 that will interest you are:

```
C-c z c - create
C-c z v - view
```

I refer you to the manuals for more details - I've included reference links below to the 2 packages

https://github.com/tlh/workgroups.el
http://workgroups2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/